# Sudoku game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, sudoku

PHP coder here. Learning JavaScript this week. I made a sudoku game for practice. Features:

- Import puzzles by pasting a text string.
- Imported squares are gray. Your squares are white.
- Program doesn't let you make a clearly illegal move. It will blank your number and color the square red for 2 seconds.
- The sudoku puzzle/game is a class. Easy to add methods and features to it later.
- Room for growth. I may add a "solve" button and a "give hints" check box later. I may add a "you won" message when you win.

Things I'm hoping to gain from this Code Review.

- Let's focus on the JavaScript. Improvements to the JavaScript code's organization, style, choice of functions, variable and function names, etc.
- Feel free to refactor completely if you want.
- Looking for that professional coder perspective so I can build good habits.
- Feel free to suggest next steps/next features.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/AdmiralAkbar2/z6rv70h4/37/

## Screenshot

[image]

## JavaScript

```
// TODO: solve button
// TODO: show hints
    // if 8 squares in a 3x3 are known, highlight 9th square
    // if 8 squares in a row are known, highlight 9th square
    // if 8 squares in a column are known, highlight 9th square

"use strict";

class Sudoku {
  constructor() {
        this.board = this.blank_board_array();
    }
    
    blank_board_array() {
        return [
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
            [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
        ];
    }

  // I can't figure out how to get this working with the "set" keyword, so making a method for now
    set_board(board_string) {
        if ( ! board_string.match(/^\d{81}$/m) ) {
            this.board = this.blank_board_array();
            return;
        }
        
        for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
            for ( let column = 0; column <= 8; column++ ) {
                this.board[row][column] = board_string.charAt(row*9+column);
            }
        }
        
        /*
        if ( ! this.puzzle_is_valid() ) {
            this.board = this.blank_board_array();
            return;
        }
        */
    }
    
    get_board_array() {
        return this.board;
    }
    
    make_move(row, col, value) {
        this.board[row][col] = value;
    }
    
    is_legal_move(row, col, value) {
        // check for non numbers
      // weird that JS match function doesn't put quotes around regex
        if ( ! value.match(/^[1-9]$/m) ) {
            return false;
        }
        
        // check row
        for ( let i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
            if ( value == this.board[row][i] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        // check column
        for ( let i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
            if ( value == this.board[i][col] ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        // check 3x3 grid
        let row_offset = Math.floor(row/3)*3;
        let col_offset = Math.floor(col/3)*3;
        for ( let i = 0 + row_offset; i <= 2 + row_offset; i++ ) {
            for ( let j = 0 + col_offset; j <= 2 + col_offset; j++ ) {
                if ( value == this.board[i][j] ) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
};

let game1 = new Sudoku();
let import_string;
let import_button = document.getElementById('import');
let sudoku_squares = createArray(9,9);

for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
    for ( let col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ) {
        sudoku_squares[row][col] =  document.getElementsByClassName('sudoku')[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[col].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    }
}

import_button.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    import_string = document.getElementsByName("import_string")[0].value;
  game1.set_board(import_string);
    print_sudoku_to_webpage(game1);
});

for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
    for ( let col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ) {
        sudoku_squares[row][col].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
            e.target.classList.remove("invalid");
            
            if ( ! game1.is_legal_move(row, col, e.target.value) && e.target.value != "" ) {
              e.target.value = "";
                highlight_temporarily(e.target, 2000);
            } else {
                game1.make_move(row, col, e.target.value);
            }
        });
    }
}

function print_sudoku_to_webpage(sudoku_object) {
    let board = sudoku_object.get_board_array();
    clear_webpage_board();
    for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
        for ( let col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ) {
            if ( board[row][col] != 0 ) {
                let input = sudoku_squares[row][col];
                input.value = board[row][col];
                input.classList.add('imported_square');
            }
        }
    }
}

function clear_webpage_board() {
    for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
        for ( let col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ) {
            sudoku_squares[row][col].value = "";
            sudoku_squares[row][col].classList.remove('imported_square');
        }
    }
}

// This code is borrowed from another website. Thanks google.
function createArray(length) {
    var arr = new Array(length || 0),
        i = length;

    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        while(i--) arr[length-1 - i] = createArray.apply(this, args);
    }

    return arr;
}

function highlight_temporarily(obj, timeout_in_ms){
   obj.classList.add('invalid');
   setTimeout(function(){
        obj.classList.remove('invalid');
   }, timeout_in_ms);
}
```

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sudoku</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="import">
    <input type="text" name="import_string" value="080100007000070960026900130000290304960000082502047000013009840097020000600003070" />
    <br />
    <button id="import">Import</button>
    <!--
    <button id="solve">Solve</button>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="hints" /> Show Hints
    -->
</div>

<table class="sudoku">
    <tbody>
    <tr class="1">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="2">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="3 thick_bottom">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="4">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="5">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="6 thick_bottom">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="7">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="8">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="9">
        <td class="1"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="2"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="3 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="4"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="5"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="6 thick_right"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="7"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="8"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
        <td class="9"><input type="text" maxlength="1" /></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

## CSS

```
body {font-family:sans-serif;}

.import {padding-bottom:0.2em;}
.import input[type=text] {width:630px;}

.valid {background-color:limegreen;}
.invalid {background-color:red;}
.imported_square {background-color:lightgray;}

.sudoku {border:4px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
.sudoku tr {padding:0;}
.sudoku td {padding:0; border:1px solid black; width:1em;}
.sudoku input {width:1em; border:0; font-size:25pt; text-align:center;}
.sudoku .thick_right {border-right:4px solid black !important;}
.sudoku .thick_bottom {border-bottom:4px solid black;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is mostly easy to read- indentation seems consistent, though the CSS rules are not separated by new lines - a common convention among many style guides. There are a few comments and many functions/methods are self-documenting but it would be good to comment each function/method to be thorough, especially if you intend to have others utilize the code.

It looks like some [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) features are used - e.g. Classes, but more could be used- e.g. [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and perhaps [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), etc.

Some variables are actually declared as global - e.g. `game1`, `import_string`, etc. - since they are not contained inside a function. That is likely not an issue for a small application like this but in a larger application it would be wise to limit the scopes (e.g. inside an IIFE, DOM-loaded callback, etc. to avoid namespace collisions.

---

The biggest thing I notice that is sub-optimal is this block:

> ```
>  for ( let row = 0; row <= 8; row++ ) {
>    for ( let col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ) {
>         sudoku_squares[row][col] =  document.getElementsByClassName('sudoku')[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[row].getElementsByTagName('td')[col].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
>     }
> }
> ```

Not only is that line inside the nested loop excessively long, but it means there are 81 DOM lookups just for the first element with class *sudoku*, plus DOM lookups for each of the child elements.

[image: bridge toll]

> *”...DOM access is actually pretty costly - I think of it like if I have a bridge - like two pieces of land with a toll bridge,  and the JavaScript engine is on one side, and the DOM is on the other, and every time I want to access the DOM from the JavaScript engine, I have to pay that toll”*
>       - John Hrvatin, Microsoft, MIX09, in [this talk *Building High Performance Web Applications and Sites*](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX09/T53F) at 29:38, also cited in the [O'Reilly *Javascript* book by Nicholas C Zakas Pg 36](https://books.google.com/books?id=ED6ph4WEIoQC&pg=PA36&lpg=PA36&dq=John+Hrvatin+%22DOM%22&source=bl&ots=2Wrd5G2ceJ&sig=pjK9cf9LGjlqw1Z6Hm6w8YrWOio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjcmZ7U_eDeAhVMGDQIHSfUAdoQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=John%20Hrvatin%20%22DOM%22&f=false), as well as mentioned in [this post](https://www.learnsteps.com/javascript-increase-performance-by-handling-dom-with-care/)

One could simply add an *id* attribute to the table element and then access the [`rows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) property instead of querying for the rows, and access the [`cells`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement#Properties) property of each row instead of querying for them. Another simplification would be to use `document.querySelectorAll()` with a selector like `.sudoku input` to get a collection of the inputs.

---

Similar to PHP’s `foreach` loops, [`for..of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could be used instead of the `for` loops to avoid having to manually increment the counter variables.

Instead of blocks like this:

```
for ( let i = 0; i <= 8; i++ ) {
    if ( value == this.board[row][i] ) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

simplify it like this:

```
for ( const cell of this.board[row]) {
    if ( value == cell ) {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

---

The method `blank_board_array` could be a static method since it doesn’t need to reference any state of the instance. The same could apply to some of the other helper functions. Additionally, `createArray()` could be used instead of `blank_board_array()`. And that could perhaps be simplified by utilizing [`Array.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

---

Instead of using `let` for all block-scope variables, it is wise to default to using `const` to avoid accidental re-assignment. Then when you determine re-assignment is necessary use `let` (e.g. for counters, etc.).

---

The mouse up event handler for the import button starts with this line:

> ```
>   import_string = document.getElementsByName("import_string")[0].value
> ```

It would be simpler to add an *id* attribute to that element and then use `document.getElementById()` to reference it- that way there is no need to fetch a collection of elements just to get the first one.

If all elements were wrapped in a `<form>` tag then that element could be referenced by `document.forms[0].import_string` but then you would have to ensure the form didn’t get submitted.

Also it would likely be wise to use the `click` event instead of `mouseup` - that way if the user preferred using the keyboard to tab through elements it would allow pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to also trigger the event handler.

---

The e.g. [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) could be used to transform this:

> ```
> var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
> ```

To this:

```
const args = [...arguments].slice(1);
```

Or [`Array.shift()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) could be used to take the first argument off the array, eliminating the need to call `slice()`.

Or use destructuring assignment to assign those variables.

```
function createArray() {
    const [length = 0, ...remainingArgs] = arguments;
    var arr = new Array(length),
    i = length;
    if (remainingArgs.length) {
        while(i--) arr[length-1 - i] = createArray(...remainingArgs);
    }
```

---

There is one CSS rule containing `!important`:

> ```
> .sudoku .thick_right {border-right:4px solid black !important;}
> ```

It is best to create a rule that is more specific than any others instead of using `!important`.

> When an important rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it. Using !important, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) in your stylesheets. When two conflicting declarations with the `!important` rule are applied to the same element, the declaration with a greater specificity will be applied.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception)</sup>

There happen to be no other `border-right` rules that need to be overridden so that keyword can be removed here.

---

The table rows and cells have class names like “1”, “2”. I don't see any CSS or JavaScript that utilizes those class names. While "CSS2.1 it is a recommendation, even in CSS3"<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)</sup> class names should not start with a number:

> Property names and [at-rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#at-rule) names are always [identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#identifier), which have to start with a letter or a hyphen followed by a letter, and then can contain letters, numbers, hyphens, or underscores. You can include any [code point](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#code-point) at all, even ones that CSS uses in its syntax, by [escaping](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#escape-codepoint) it.<sup>[3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#syntax-description)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed feedback. I will spend today refactoring my code to incorporate these suggestions. I love Code Review - people are nicer than on Stack Overflow, and the answers are incredibly helpful : )

Comment: What other ES6 features could I potentially use? You mention this in line 1 of your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to mention more examples

Comment: You're a legend. Thank you for adding that. I've incorporated a lot of your suggestions into the latest fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/AdmiralAkbar2/z6rv70h4/226/ . I will continue incorporating suggestions from this code review, and perhaps post a part 2 in a week or two.

Comment: Nice - I added some notes about CSS as well

Answer (score 5):

To add to existing review a few points I noticed:

- You are mixing up under_score (`clear_webpage_board`) and camelCase naming (`createArray`). Typically functions in javascript use camelCase (you can see that in all built-in methods that you use, including the borrowed `createArray`).
- Css on the other hand typically uses naming, where dash is used, so `thick-right`, not `thick_right`. Ye it's a bit annoying that every technology has different convention naming.
- I don't like your namings very much. `print_sudoku_to_webpage`. That method sychronizes your data with html elements, that represent it. I would call it maybe `displayBoard` or something (since you call it "board" in another function. `print` feels off, you don't print anything. `webpage` also (duh, you are on a webpage, we know that). `clear_webpage_board`  again drop `webpage`, no point.
- How to use your code if I wanted more sudoku boards on one page? It wouldn't work, because you are always looking for first element with class "sudoku". It feels like there should be one class representing `Sudoku`, independent from HTML (you have that) and then there should be another class, that can display it in UI, handle events and pass those events to game itself. That class can know this "root element" with class "sudoku" and look for rest of pieces inside of it using `querySelector` as our colleague in other answer mentioned. That would also clean all your cycles and code, that doesn't have function anywhere.
- Consider extracting repeating strings to constants - that will help avoiding bugs. If you make typo mistake in one place but not another, sometimes it's hard to debug. Same goes for numbers - that would also make it easier to generate sudoku with different dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll change my variable names and shorten the verbose method names. I probably won't refactor the code to print multiple sudoku boards on the same page, it would increase complexity and is not a feature I am likely to use. YAGNI. I'll probably post a part 2 in a week or two.

Comment: Up to you, depends what do you want from the project. I don't see it as YAGNI. I see it as practice of SRP and separating of concerns. Either way keep up the good work, good luck!

Comment: Maybe you're right. What's the best way to implement this? I'd have to replace all my HTML ID's with classes right? Then have the user put something like <div class="sudoku"></div> in their HTML, and my code would insert the Sudoku there, correct? How would I keep track of each unique div/sudoku since it doesn't have an ID? Feel free to edit your answer if you need more space. Thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, more up to date fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/AdmiralAkbar2/z6rv70h4/229/

Comment: Pass "root" element (ex your `.sudoku` div) to HTML rendering class. If you wanna keep track of it all root elements, you do it outside of your sudoku classes. HTML rendering class doesn't need to care about IDs, other roots etc. Try to separate concerns and make classes as simple as possible :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's start with some convention things, in JS we (everyone) write function and variable names as camel case.

I see you have a comment that you tried to use a setter, the issue is that you would then want to use it in two ways. You would want to write this.board = import_string to call the setter, but in the constructor you do

`this.board = this.blank_board_array();`

You could use a setter with some rewriting, but I think it's fine as is.

The double equals in JS `==` coerces the types, so that for example `0==[]` is true, while this can be useful, in my experience it fits squarely in the realm of being too clever, or of things working coincidentally. I would advise you always use `===` which does not coerce types (but controversially to my colleagues I write lines like `if (x === false)`, some say this is a step too far).

I would suggest that it would be nicer to have functions which create an html Sudoku board, i.e. rather than target elements that happen to be there, you can make the elements with JS and then add a single element (with many children) at the end, if you do this you can also tidy up the logic of setting up the event listeners a lot too.

In general there's been a trend (at least in my experience working) towards writing quite functional code in JS. Your stuff is far removed from that, not really a problem, just something to be aware of.

It's a bit hard to give an example without just rewriting everything, but for instance (though the example I will give is still not very functional) several times you loop over a 2D array, you could write a function loopOverMatrix(matrix, f) which  takes a 2D array and a function f (i, j) => {...}, and loops over all the elements [i][j] and calls f(i)(j).

Comment: "if you do this you can also tidy up the logic of setting up the event listeners a lot too." I'd be willing to try this. What's your idea? Can you give an example?

Comment: By the way, here's the current code. I moved all the listeners into a DOMContentLoaded listener. https://jsfiddle.net/AdmiralAkbar2/z6rv70h4/229/

Comment: Sure, here I wrote an example of what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/y5j92eno/3/. Now you could just use the sudoku variable to do manipulations, better yet, you could add more properties to the object you pass into makeSudokuGrid to better initialise it. Regarding your code now, I write OOP code (in other languages) so know something of it, and from that perspective it's great, and what you're doing is just generally well done. But I would strongly advise that if learning JS is for more than just fun that you try doing things in the more functional way.